# resetar efeitos após clicar em um link

Tags: html, css

Como posso resetar todos os efeitos após clicar em um link **a**

Ex, esse efeito sublinhado e a borda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use o outline

```
a:focus, a:visited, a:hover {
   outline: 0;
   border: none;
}
```